# Como fazer aparecer 4 na esquerda e 5 na direita simultaneamente

Tags: assembly

Com o programa sms32v50, estou tentando obter o número 45, até então está assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Start:
MOV    AL,FA  ; 1111 1010

```
   OUT    02     ; Send the data in AL to Port 02

   MOV    AL,0   ; 0000 0000

   OUT    02     ; Send the data in AL to Port 02

  

   MOV    AL,FB  ; 1111 1011

   OUT    02     ; Send the data in AL to Port 02

   MOV    AL,1   ; 0000 0001

   OUT    02     ; Send the data in AL to Port 02

   JMP    Start

   END
```

Answer (score 0):

A sequencia binária responsável por acender os leds corretos do numero 4 seria o valor 4E (0100 1110) e o 5 seria sendo o valor DD (1101 1101), para limpar bastaria enviar 0 (0000 0000) e 1 (0000 0001) para o port 2.

```
INICIO:

;exibe 4e = 0100 1110
mov al,4e
out 2

;exibe dd = 1101 1101
mov al,dd
out 2

;zera 
mov al,0
out 2
mov al,1
out 2

;loop
jmp INICIO

END
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a ordem dos bits no display seria isso (lembrando que o b7 seria MSB, e o b0 LSB)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]